# Raster functions for PostgreSQL and PostGIS on Mac

Tags: postgis, postgresql, raster2pgsql

I am in a class on spatial databases. I have PostgreSQL and PostGIS on my MacBook Pro and have successfully completed several assignments involving shapefiles and other data, so I know both programs work. I am also working with QGIS 3.22. We are now supposed to import a raster file with raster2pgsql and do queries on it, but I cannot figure out how to import it on my Mac. All instruction we have is for Windows, and I am not very familiar with using the terminal. If I go to my terminal and type raster2pgsql I get this as a result "zsh: command not found: raster2pgsql." Is there a way to use raster2pgsl on a Mac?